# Using Google Email Mark up on shopify

Tags: google-schemas

I wonder how to properly use Google Email Markup in our emails to be send to the customer?I tried to apply it under the notification on shopify settings, I dont really know if it works.

This is the script for Parcel Delivery

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "ParcelDelivery",
  "deliveryAddress": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "24 Willie Mays Plaza",
    "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
    "addressRegion": "CA",
    "addressCountry": "US",
    "postalCode": "94107"
  },
  "expectedArrivalUntil": "2013-03-12T12:00:00-08:00",
  "carrier": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "FedEx"
  },
  "itemShipped": {
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "iPod Mini"
  },
  "partOfOrder": {
    "@type": "Order",
    "orderNumber": "176057",
    "merchant": {
      "@type": "Organization",
      "name": "Bob Dole"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```